# The [NeutralResourceLanguage] attribute is missing on the entry assembly

Tags: windows-phone-7, msdn, marketplace

I'm trying to submit an app to the windows phone 7 marketplace and have never encountered this error when validating my .xap package. App Hub just remodeled and became back online roughly an hour ago. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm getting the same thing.. Maybe their new update they just made doesn't work?

Found it...
Update Assembly.cs with this:

```
using System.Resources;  // Add this to the top..

[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

This worked for me.. Cheers..

Note per Blakomen:

If you are submitting an application for worldwide publishing, you should use NeutralResourcesLanguage("en"), not just "en-US" or it won't show up in the marketplace if you're trying to publish to UK marketplace, for example (it will for some reason come up for Korea and Japan though)

Comment: This is a new requirement of the app hub (ready for Mango) where all applications must now have a neutral resource language specified. This is to allow the correct support for the new langauges that Mango supports.

Comment: Just a note that if you are submitting an application for worldwide publishing, you should use NeutralResourcesLanguage("en"), not just "en-US" or it won't show up in the marketplace if you're trying to publish to UK marketplace, for example (it will for some reason come up for Korea and Japan though)

Answer (score 19):

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name, and click Properties.
- Under the Application tab, click the Assembly Information button.
- In the Neutral Language list, select the default culture.

This worked for me. My application didn't have a default language specified, so in the update I've set it to English. Anyway now I'm stuck at the "No Keywords or Description (Missing)" bug, good luck.

Source:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/87530.aspx

Comment: Great answer! Both your and Devo's answers worked for me. I prefer your way but already gave the check mark away. Sorry! Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.  After adding the NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US"), I got another error from app hub saying that I can't change previously submitted language.  Then I used NeutralResourcesLanguage(null) followed by a weird unexpected error message from app hub recommending me that now might be an excellent time to go out for a walk :)  Seriously!!!

Comment: Hah interesting :) I had the same problem then I checked details on my application and it said English(international) so I added [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en")] instead and it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Open the AssemblyInfo.cs from your project and add the following at the top "using System.Resources;"

There is a new requirement of the app hub (ready for Mango) where all applications must now have a neutral resource language specified.

```
                        **OR ALTERNATIVELY TRY THIS:**
```

1. Right click your project and select "properties"
2. Click on the Assembly Info button
3. Select Neutral language and choose a language of your choice. I work with English so i just choose English and you are good to go.

   ```
                          >>> Hope it helped <<<
   ```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively can also fix this using VS2010 select your project --> right click -->  properties --> under Application tab --> click Assembly information button --> select neutral language -- English.

Bingo -- done... :-)

Hope this may help!!

Thanks and Regards
Nishant Rana

My blog- http://www.nishantcop.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a more detailed step by step on how to fix this, check out:

[Neutral Resource Language Attribute Missing](http://rehlander.com/wp7/apps/the-neutralresourcelanguage-attribute-is-missing-on-the-entry-assembly-2003)